# JasperReports 6.3 and DataStax DDC Cassandra 3.9.0

Tags: cassandra, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I would like to connect to Cassandra 3.9.0 (DataStax DDC) from JasperReports Server community edition (Product Version: 6.3.0, Build: 20160629_1853) and from Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.1.final.

When I create a Data Adapter for Cassandra Connection (no user/no password) and then click Test it works OK and says Successful. The same connection works well from cqlsh and from DatastaxDevCenter 1.6 as well.

But when I write a CQL query for my report and click "Read fields" it does not show anything. So I cannot even see Fields in my report.

My CQL query is simple:

```
select customer_name, bs_customer_id, crm_customer_id, my_id from customers
```

I could see similar questions on this forum already but no helpful answer :(

Any ideas where the issue might be? Are there any more detailed logs in Jaspersoft Studio to see what is going on when I click "Read fields"?

Comment: How many results are you expecting from your customers table?  Cassandra is *not* a good back-end for a reporting tool, because unbound queries (SELECTs without WHEREs) require full table scans from multiple nodes which are prone to time-out.

Comment: @PawełAndrzejHadam You can add fields manually (via editing *jrxml* file). `Any ideas where the issue might be?` - Maybe it is a bug. Did you try to enable log4j? [Configuring Apache Commons Logging and Log4J in Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/configuring-apache-commons-logging-and-log4j-jaspersoft-studio)

Comment: @Aaron - thank you. This table has 3 rows only now. My question is about why it does NOT work.

Comment: @AlexK 1) I added my fields manually and run the report. The report is empty. 2) Thanks for logging, however, does it also work with community edition? It does not work for me :(

Comment: `does it also work with community edition?` - Yes